# Ignite: SQL query to calculate probability of a column

Tags: sql, ignite

```
Gender
-------
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Female
```

Here i want to calculate probability of gender column and following query i tried, but it's not working.

```
SELECT (count(*)/(SELECT count(*) from DIABETIC_TOPIC) as probability from DIABETIC_TOPIC group by gender order by gender;
```

what i missed?

Comment: For starters, you have mismatched round braces.

Comment: @alamar, i fixed and tried, still not working. And the query i modified to..

SELECT count(*)/(SELECT count(*) from DIABETIC_TOPIC) from 
        DIABETIC_TOPIC group by gender order by gender;

Answer (score 0):

I'd cross join the grouped query on a non-grouped query, and divide them:

```
SELECT     gender, cnt_gender / cnt * 100 AS probability
FROM       (SELECT   gender, COUNT(*)
            FROM     diabetic_topic
            GROUP BY gender) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM   diabetic_topic) b
```